# Dom parsing for Android

Tags: android, dom

I want to parse XML which is received from a .net web service and store the parsed data into a string array. I tried so many times but the loop is terminating after one execution without any exception.

The XML which is received from web service is attached here.

```
<DocumentElement>
   <PictureList>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <WorkId>1</WorkId>
        <PictureUrl>"~/Admin/"</PictureUrl>
        <Status>Active</Status>
        <CreatedDateTime>2015-11-21T00:00:00+00:00</CreatedDateTime>
   </PictureList>
</DocumentElement>
```

code which is used for parsing is given below

```
 public void pictures(String st) {

      DocumentBuilderFactory factory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder builder;
      builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(st)));
      Element env = doc.getDocumentElement();
      NodeList nl = env.getElementsByTagName("PictureList");
      lengthsem = nl.getLength();
      length = 0;
      Node n = nl.item(0);
      NodeList nl_suc = n.getChildNodes();
      length = nl_suc.getLength();
      String[][] semres;
      String semdata[][] = new String[lengthsem][36];
      for (int i = 0; i < lengthsem; i++) {
            n = nl.item(i);
            nl_suc = n.getChildNodes();
            length = nl_suc.getLength();
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                System.out.println("length inndr" +length);
                Node n_suc = nl_suc.item(j);
                String lab = n_suc.getNodeName();
                Log.e("lab",lab);
                Log.e("fhkhgfgfkhg", n_suc.getNodeName());
                if (n_suc.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    sem = Webxml.getElementText((Element) n_suc);
                    Log.e("iloufhkhghjk,ldlfdlll", sem);

                    Log.e("fhkhghjk,ldlfdlll", lab);
                    Node hasSub = nl_suc.item(10);
                    Log.e("fhkhghjksunbb", hasSub.getNodeName());
                    String sub = Webxml.getElementText((Element) hasSub);
                    if (lab.equals("Id")) {
                        semdata[i][0] = sem;
                        System.out.println("0 " + lab + i);
                        success = "true";
                        try {
                            j++;
                            System.out.println(j + "jvalueee");
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            System.out.println("exception");
                        }
                        Log.e("fhkhghjk,ldlfdlll", lab);

                    } else if (lab.equals("WorkId")) {
                        semdata[i][1] = sem;
                        System.out.println("0 " + lab + i);
                        success = "true";
                        Log.e("fhkhghjk,ldlfdlll", lab);
                    } else if (lab.equals("PictureUrl")) {
                        semdata[i][2] = sem;
                        System.out.println("0 " + lab + i);
                        success = "true";
                        Log.e("fhkhghjk,ldlfdlll", lab);
                    } else if (lab.equals("CreatedDateTime")) {
                        semdata[i][3] = sem;
                        System.out.println("0 " + lab + i);
                        success = "true";
                        Log.e("fhkhghjk,ldlfdlll", lab);

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("test111");
                        break;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
```

Comment: Can you please include the relevant portion of your code?  We won't be able to help you diagnose the problem otherwise.

Comment: sure. the parsing code is given below. and thankz for your immediate response.

Comment: @kiwidrew i attached the relevant portion as your response. please help me

Answer (score 0):

Well i worked some kind of same data so i can suggest you this way. you can use it also.

```
   String[][] strarray = new String[0][10];
  try {

        mDbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = mDbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        mDocument = db.parse(is);
        mDocument.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


  NodeList nodeList = mDocument.getElementsByTagName("PictureList");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);


        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element element = (Element) node;
            strarray[0][i] =  getValue("Id", element);
            strarray[0][i] = getValue("WorkId", element));
            strarray[0][i] = getValue("PictureUrl", element));
            strarray[0][i] = getValue("Status", element));
            strarray[0][i] = getValue("CreatedDateTime", element));


        }

    }


public String getValue(String stag, Element mElement) {
    String value = "";
    NodeList nlList = mElement.getElementsByTagName(stag).item(0)
            .getChildNodes();
    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
    if (nValue != null) {
        value = nValue.getTextContent();
    }
    return value;
}
```

I changed it for string array. so it can be logically wrong somewhere.